# Waking up a sleeping thread on sigint in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust, sleep, sigint

Consider the following simple Rust program:

```
use std::time::Duration;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::thread;
use ctrlc;

static running: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(true);

fn main() {

    // Set up a thread that registers the sigint signal.
    ctrlc::set_handler(|| {
        running.store(false, Ordering::SeqCst);
    });

    // Loop as long as the signal has not been registered.
    while running.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
        println!("Hello!");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
    }
    println!("Goodbye!");

}
```

It prints "Hello!" every ten seconds until someone press Ctrl+C, upon which it prints "Goodbye!" and exit. The problem is if Ctrl+C is pressed right after the thread goes to sleep. The user then has to wait for almost ten seconds until the program exits.

Is there any way to get around this, and somehow wake up the thread when the sigint signal is recieved? I'm prepared to change the [ctrlc](https://docs.rs/ctrlc/3.1.3/ctrlc/) dependency for something else if it helps.

The only solution I have been able to come up with is to sleep during ten one second intervals instead, checking sigint before going back to sleep again at every wakeup. Is there a simpler and prettier way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

As the [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.sleep.html#platform-specific-behavior) says:

> On Unix platforms, the underlying syscall may be interrupted by a spurious wakeup or signal handler. To ensure the sleep occurs for at least the specified duration, this function may invoke that system call multiple times. Platforms which do not support nanosecond precision for sleeping will have `dur` rounded up to the nearest granularity of time they can sleep for.

So, I propose you to use a more low level [function](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.60/libc/fn.clock_nanosleep.html) directly, there is one crates that encapsule it [`shuteye`](https://docs.rs/shuteye/0.3.3/shuteye/fn.sleep.html), but I don't know if it's a good one.